# Twilio voice call(made from android app to mobile phone) isn't disconnecting on phone end when caller from android end loses internet connection

Tags: android, twilio

1) I am using twilio voice android sdk not twilio client.

2) I am making twilio app to phone call and the receiver party on phone isn't disconnecting when the caller party who called from android app loses internet completely (though caller on android app end gets disconnected when internet connection is lost.).

What am i missing here can it be managed from android end or it needs to be done from server(in my case php)?

i need help.

Comment: share your code snippet

Comment: What TwiML are you using to connect the two callers?

Comment: i am using dial verb for making a call

Answer (score 0):

[Disconnecting a Call with Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/client/outgoing-calls#hanging-up-a-call)

**Following code called by sdk that when get disconnected.**

```
private void disconnect() {
    if (activeConnection != null) {
        activeConnection.disconnect();
        activeConnection = null;
    }
}
```

***For more enhance user experience you can use broadcast receiver for same.***